# Dynamic links in php

Tags: php, html

I'm almost embarrassed asking this question since I know it should be quite simple yet I can't find an answer to it.

I have a html page with php code in it, that displays let's say a list of companies in a table. I want to make the names of the companies in the table be hyperlinks, such that when a user clicks on a company name, he/she is taken to a page that shows that company's details.

The issue is I cannot have a static page for each company because this list of companies can change every day. So the 'company details' page should be generated dynamically based on what the user clicks.

I am not sure how to approach this. all the questions I see out there seem to talk about static links and pages for static data.

Any guidance is be appreciated!

Comment: You have a database with company information?

Comment: if you can show your code where you get the company list from and in what format then I'm sure the guys can help you

Comment: so, if some are not assigned a link, then use a ternary operator with blank/default values; if that's what the question is about. Using a `WHERE` clause in the query is also something you could/should use. Question's unclear though as to the code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every company in the table should have an ID property.

Then when you create the link, do something like this:

```
<a href="/company_details.php?id=<?php echo $companyId; ?>">Company Name</a>
```

In your `company_details.php` you can get the ID of the company from `$_GET['id']`.

That way you only have one page `company_details.php` for all companies.

Comment: That doesn't answer how the page will generate the company information once the link is used.

Comment: I assume he has a database where he stores the companies

Comment: Thanks Madzgo. I found a similar solution to yours and was finally able to get it to work. I created a companydetails.php page and i append the company ID to the url when calling the page and use $_GET['id'] to get the company and fire the SQL query from inside the page. I'll mark your answer as accepted even though I found it from another answer since your answer is the right way to do it.